# Elm Language Coding Error

Tags: variable-assignment, elm

```
type Expr = Const Float | Var String| Add Expr Expr| Mult Expr Expr

list = [3,1,4]

polyX : List Float -> Expr
polyX coeffs = polyHelper <| map Const <| coeffs
polyHelper: List Expr -> Expr
polyHelper e = case e of
     [x] -> x
     (x::xs) -> Add x(Mult(Var "x")(polyHelper xs))
     [] -> Const 1

type Instr = LoadImmediate RegisterNumber --put value here
                           RegisterValue  --the value

           | Addition      RegisterNumber --put result here
                           RegisterNumber --first thing to add
                           RegisterNumber --first thing to multiply

           | Multiply      RegisterNumber --put result here
                           RegisterNumber --first thing to multiply
                           RegisterNumber --second thing to multiply

type RegisterNumber = Int
type RegisterValue = Float

expr2Code : Expr -> List Instr
expr2Code expr = e2C 1 expr

e2C result expr = case expr of
                 Const x -> ((LoadImmediate(result+2))x)
                 Add expr1 expr2 -> (Addition result result (result+1))::(e2C result expr2)++(e2C result expr1)
                 Mult expr1 expr2 -> (Mult result result(result+1))::(e2C result expr2)++(e2C result expr1)
                 Var x -> []
```

I am having difficulty with an assignment.

Question:

> Assume that the only variable you will see is x and it is already in register 2. Arrange for the result to arrive to be in register 1 at the end of the computation, and use registers 3 and 4 for other values, as needed. Write the helper function e2C to complete.

My T.A says that the code I have right now will compile, but it will not solve for the question.

Can anyone tell me how to fix the code so it will solve for the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Getting it to compile

Well, you're TA is wrong, that code snippet does not compile. Here's a compiling version:

```
type Expr
  = Const Float
  | Var String
  | Add Expr Expr
  | Mult Expr Expr

type Instr
  = LoadImmediate RegisterNumber --put value here
                  RegisterValue  --the value
  | Addition      RegisterNumber --put result here
                  RegisterNumber --first thing to add
                  RegisterNumber --first thing to multiply
  | Multiply      RegisterNumber --put result here
                  RegisterNumber --first thing to multiply
                  RegisterNumber --second thing to multiply

type alias RegisterNumber
  = Int

type alias RegisterValue
  = Float

list : List Float
list =
  [3,1,4]

polyX : List Float -> Expr
polyX coeffs =
  polyHelper <| List.map Const <| coeffs

polyHelper: List Expr -> Expr
polyHelper e =
  case e of
    [x] ->
      x

    (x::xs) ->
      Add x (Mult (Var "x") (polyHelper xs))

    [] ->
      Const 1

expr2Code : Expr -> List Instr
expr2Code expr =
  e2C 1 expr

e2C : RegisterNumber -> Expr -> List Instr
e2C result expr =
  case expr of
    Const x ->
      [LoadImmediate (result+2) x]

    Add expr1 expr2 ->
      Addition result result (result+1)
      :: e2C result expr2 ++ e2C result expr1

    Mult expr1 expr2 ->
      Multiply result result (result+1)
      :: e2C result expr2 ++ e2C result expr1

    Var x ->
      []
```

I've formatted the code more in accordance with the [style guide](http://elm-lang.org/docs/style-guide). I found the following problems before your code compiled:

1. `polyX` used an unqualified `map` function, but there are no imports, so you should use the qualified `List.map`.
2. The types `RegisterNumber` and `RegisterValue` are type *aliases*. Use `type alias` for those, otherwise you're defining **constructors** `Int` and `Float` for completely independent types `RegisterNumber` and `RegisterValue` instead of relating those to the **types** `Int and`Float`.
3. The `Const` branch in `e2C` wasn't returning a list, but the other branches of the `case` were.
4. The `Mult` branch in `e2C` was using `Mult` instead of `Multiply` for the result, which is an `Expr`, not an `Instr`.

## Getting it to work

**DISCLAIMER:** Check you school/course regulations on FRAUD. In my experience, students are expected to submit only solutions that they wrote themselves. High-level discussions about solutions are usually OK, copying code is most likely NOT OK. This answer may go into too much detail according to your school's fraud regulations. Citing your sources is not always enough!

Given the three instructions that you can do, it's not easy to move a result from one register into another. That'll require bogus instructions like `[LoadImmediate freeRegister 0, Addition moveToThisRegister MoveFromThisRegister freeRegister]`. So you can't elegantly create an elaborate compiler, and you probably don't have to, given that you're only asked to complete helper function `e2C`.

So we're going for the easy, non-general solution. You'll want to make some assumptions about the `Expr` that you get in. Note that `polyX` only generates additions and multiplications that have a somehow constant (`Const` or `Var`) left-hand side. This is the property we'll exploit.

So if you do the right-hand side expressions first, and give that expression the same result register that you're given, then you still have both free registers (3 and 4) for your left-hand side. Use only one of them consistently, then do the operation between the result register and the chosen free register.

Moving the value of variable x to a different register is kind of ugly when there is no move operation. But it's fairly general, so let's use the left-over free register to add 0 to the value of variable x and save that value to the register that we're supposed to put the result in. This gives you the following implementation:

```
registerOfX : RegisterNumber
registerOfX = 2

freeRegister1 : RegisterNumber
freeRegister1 = 3

freeRegister2 : RegisterNumber
freeRegister2 = 4

e2C : RegisterNumber -> Expr -> List Instr
e2C resultRegister expr =
  case expr of
    Const value ->
      [LoadImmediate resultRegister value]

    Add expr1 expr2 ->
      e2C resultRegister expr2
      ++ e2C freeRegister1 expr1
      ++ [Addition resultRegister freeRegister1 resultRegister]

    Mult expr1 expr2 ->
      e2C resultRegister expr2
      ++ e2C freeRegister1 expr1
      ++ [Multiply resultRegister freeRegister1 resultRegister]

    Var "x" ->
      [LoadImmediate freeRegister2 0, Addition resultRegister registerOfX freeRegister2]

    Var _ ->
      "Cannot handle "
      ++ toString expr
      ++ ", we only know of "
      ++ toString (Var "x")
      |> Debug.crash
```

One final note, since this is already a long answer. You'll see that this code results in some redundant `LoadImmediate 4 0` instructions. You can add a signal instruction for it to the front of the list by doing something like `LoadImmediate freeRegister2 0 :: case expr of ...`. Then you can move variable x to a register in one instruction. Any further minimisation of the instructions will require extra steps that are best done in further helper functions, or you'll need to make the code less general by directly matching on `Mult (Var "x") expr2` and use the register of variable x directly.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping! But for the case Var _ ->, I have never learned this. Does Var _ -> [ ] work?

Comment: @Eliscpe sure, you can return an empty list. That does mean that your program will output garbage instructions when it hits a variable that isn't x. Not something I'd recommend in real software, but if that's what's expected of you for the assignment, go for it.

Comment: I was told that Var "x" is wrong, because i am already told the value of x is already in register 2. How would I fix this?

Comment: @Eliscpe sorry, I don't know any of your course material, so I have no idea how they want you to design the program.